# fuzzy matching with multiple words

Tags: r, fuzzy-search

I'm trying to do some fuzzy matching in R, where I have multiple fields of data to match against.

For example:

```
try_to_match <- c('seoul korea', 'bisbane', 'korea', 'australia brisbane')
locations <- data.frame(name=c('seoul', 'brisbane'),
                        country=c('south korea', 'australia'))
```

I want to match the user-entered locations in `try_to_match` to the `locations` dataframe.

Now, there are similar questions about fuzzy matching with R on SO, and most cover `agrep`. However, I can't find any that cover fuzzy matching when there are multiple words to match over.

For example, if I match just against `locations$name`, I get a match for "bisbane" to "brisbane", as I expect. Also, I get no matches for the various searches with country in them, as `locations$name` has no country in it.

```
sapply(try_to_match, agrep, locations$name, value=T)
# $`seoul korea`
# character(0)    
# $bisbane
# [1] "brisbane"    
# $korea
# character(0)
# $`australia brisbane`
# character(0)
```

So, I guess I should incorporate matching with the country too:

```
sapply(try_to_match, agrep, paste(locations$name, locations$country), value=T)
# $`seoul korea`
# character(0)    
# $bisbane
# [1] "brisbane australia"    
# $korea
# [1] "seoul south korea"    
# $`australia brisbane`
# character(0)
```

However, I still cannot match "seoul korea" to "seoul south korea" because of the missing word. Likewise, while "brisbane australia" would match appropriately, "australia brisbane" does not (because the order of the words is reversed). (It is a bit iffy "korea" would match "seoul south korea", but I'm happy for this to stay for now).

So, my question is: **how to do fuzzy matching when the search *and* match terms may have multiple words and be individually mis-spelled, and the order of the words can be different?**

Is there a package to do this sort of searching for me?

(Yes, I can use the excellent geonames web service to do a lot of my matching, but I want to avoid making many requests to its server. I'm more interested in the ability to do this sort of search in R than the ability to geocode).

Comment: Could you split into words, and calculate agrep on all combinations?

Comment: I guess - although I've downloaded GeoNames' cities dump (131000 cities), and each of these has aliases making for ~500k names that could partially or completely match with or without countries. testing all combinations of words of the search terms against all combinations of words of the (aliases + country name) sounds pretty slow, and I wondered if R had some ability to do this sort of thing already before I attempt it myself.

Comment: I suspect you're trying to re-invent existing algorithms and further that these algorithms are quite non-trivial.  Given the multiple junk-mail catalogs I get addressed to, e.g. me with and without a middle initial in my name, or  "____ Road"  vs. "_____Street",  you're headed for a serious uphill battle.

Comment: I have the same feeling too. I just had hoped that R, as sophisticated as it was, had some of these algorithms in it already.